# Does urinating from the tree stand ruin your hunt?

Tags: hunting

When you're up in the tree stand and need to urinate, is it okay to do it just from above or should one seek another solution? So, does your game somehow smell the urine and will stay away? Any other considerations?

Comment: Depends if your male or female and if your on heat or not ;)

Comment: I've read anecdotes (none of them scientific) that suggest that many animals ignore the urine of other species.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it compromises your hunt.  Urine is one of the most important smells that game animals use to communicate with each other, so it is a smell they are most attuned to.  During mating season, urine tells the males when females are in estrus, and also the relative health of the animals.

When I am hunting and I find a fresh urination spot, I smell it and I can tell quite a bit about what happened, including whether it was deer or elk, sex of the elk, and how old it is, so if a lowly human can do it, you know a deer or elk can definitely do it.  You can seek another solution, like using a bottle, but I am paranoid enough about the odor that I am afraid of any leakage.  I do everything I can to avoid any sort of urine smell on me while I hunt including peeing well before I get to my spot and not drinking too much water in the stand.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think the answer depends on where you're hunting. I hunt on farm land quite a bit. There are all types of un-natural smells around farm land and there are plenty of deer about, they get used to it. However, if you're hunting in the deep woods that humans only venture into rarely, an unusual odor can be problematic.